# Extending a Protocol where Self: Generic Type in Swift (Requires Arguments In <...>)

Tags: swift

I have a class that takes a generic `class Collection: <T: Model>` (`Model` is a class) and a protocol (`Resource`) that some of the subclasses of `Collection` implement:

```
class Collection: <T: Model> {
  typealias Callback = (result: Collection <T>) -> ()
}
protocol Resource {...}
```

Is it possible to write a protocol extension where `Self` is an instance of `Collection`?

**Trying to extend the protocol with the class that takes a generic:**

```
extension Resource where Self: Collection {
  func fetch() {}
}
```

Gives:

> Reference to generic type 'Collection' requires arguments in <...>

**Trying to extend the class that takes a generic with the protocol:**

```
extension Collection where Self: Resource {
  func fetch(callback: Callback?) {}
}
```

Gives:

> 'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of  method in a class

I'm not sure how to proceed. The goal is for the function to only be available on instances of `Collection` that conform to `Resource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `Collection` is a generic class so every where you declare it, you must attached the specialized type, like `Collection<T>`. However extension to a protocol can't be specified with a generic type so you end up not being able to supply `T` to `Collection`.

In your case though, `T` is constrained to be of type `Model` so why not use that in the default protocol implementation:

```
extension Resource where Self: Collection<Model> {
    func fetch() {
        // default implementation
    }
}
```