# Swift: extending sequences with a generic element

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, protocol-extension

In Swift, one can extend a sequence that contains elements of a particular type, e.g.:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == Rect {
  func intersection() -> Rect? { ... }
}

// when using
let intersection = [rect1, rect2, rect3].intersection()
```

which is nice. However, how can I do the same thing if Rect itself is a generic type (e.g. `Rect<Float>`, `Rect<Double>` etc.)? I tried

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == Rect<T>
```

but the compiler complains about 'undeclared type T'. I can't quite figure out where to put it. Right now, I have to specialise for every floating-point type.

Comment: This looks quite similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357346/extending-a-protocol-where-self-generic-type-in-swift-requires-arguments-in.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! This must be one of those NYI type system features then.